# extract array of string values based on specific keys

Tags: json, jq

I hope everyone is well.

I am struggling with JQ trying to  select array of strings values from an input json using specific keys to select. The "key":["string1",... , "stringn"] can be embeded "somewhere" at any depth in the json. I only know the key values of the arrays.

Let's say I have some json that includes the keys dictionnay (dict) and the json source (source). In this exemple, I would like to select the "key4" and "key11" arrays and get them in a result json with the corresponding keys.

My sample input is :

```
 {
    "dict": ["key4", "key11"],
    "source":{
    "key0": {
        "key1": "valueA",
        "key2": 123456,
        "key3": [{
                "key4": ["anotherValue4341", "anotherValue4342"],
                "key5": [{
                    "someKey351": "someValue351"
                }, {
                    "someKey352": "someValue352"
                }],
                "key6": 999
            },
            {
                "key7": "anotherValue342",
                "key8": "anotherValue352",
                "key9": 666
            }
        ],
        "key10": {
            "key11": ["lastvalue111", "lastvalue112", "lastvalue113"]
        }
    }

}}
```

my expected output for this sample would be :

```
{
    "key4": ["anotherValue4341", "anotherValue4342"],
    "key11": ["lastvalue111", "lastvalue112", "lastvalue113"]
}
```

I am using JQ to extract the requested output.

for now I have attempted to reuse former query to select key/values like this :

```
jq '.dict as $dict | .source | reduce paths as $p (.;getpath($p) as $v| if $v|type == "string" and $dict[$v] then setpath($p; $dict[$v]) else . end)'
```

but it seems it struggles with some values : jq: error (at :26): Cannot index array with string "valueA"

I also have attempted to select matching objects that contains keys in dict :

```
jq '.dict as $dict | .source | recurse(.[]?) | objects | select(in($dict))'
```

but this leads to error "Cannot check whether array has a object key"

I hope I am clear enough to explain my needs/issues.

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let's start by assuming the core task is to fetch the value(s) associated with
one specific key.  For purposes of exposition and clarity, let's define a function accordingly:

```
# Emit a (possibly empty) stream of key-value objects 
# corresponding to the $key specified as a string
def getKeyValue($key):
  .. | objects | select(has($key)) | {($key): .[$key]};
```

A solution to the problem is now trivial:

```
[.dict[] as $k | getKeyValue($k)] | add
```

### Variations

This solution has several potential problems:

- It is possible that one or more of the keys of interest does not occur at all in the input;
- It is possible that one or more of the keys of interest occurs more than once in the input;
- If the input is large, then a more efficient solution might be preferable.

The first two issues can be easily dealt with, but the details will depend on the detailed requirements.
The efficiency issue can likewise be easily dealt with by modifying the def of getKeyValue so that
the named argument is an array of strings.

Comment: Thank you so much for the split problem approach. Your solution already handles the missing key problem. duplicates would be another requirement but it is not occuring for now.

Answer (score 1):

As a learning experience (for both of us), here's a version that resembles your last example:

```
.source as $source 
| [ 
  .dict[] | . as $key 
  | $source | .. 
  | select(.[$key]?) 
  | { ($key): .[$key]? } 
] | add
```

Which starts our capturing `.source` as `$source`, then it iterates over `.dict[]`, aliasing each key in it as `$key`. Then it switches back to `$source` and recurses over it (with `..`, which is a shorter version of `recurse(.[]?)`. Then the `select` looks for any sub-objects with a key named `$key`, and the following object constructor extracts that single key/value pair. Finally `add` merges all of those objects into one.

I don't make any promises that this is better or faster than the other solutions, but it's illustrative :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a recursive function. Something like

```
function {
    foreach $array as $key => $value {
        if ($key == KEYYOUWANT) {
           $answer = value
           break;
       } else {
            function($value)
       }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the pseudo code!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Sorry I may not have been clear but I am using JQ to process this json and I am looking for a JQ query to do the job. Even if the general spirit is a recursive query, in that you are right.